# How to initialize a class object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a Javascript class say "myjavascript.js". I have the following class:

```
var myClass= function () {
        this.property2 = '';
        this.property3 = '';
        this.property4 = '';
        this.property5 = '';
        
        this.say() = function () {
            alert('Say Hello');
        }
```

I have a function which is triggered on some event.

```
function myFunction(){
var myClassObj= new myClass();
myClassObj.property2 = 'property2' ;
myClassObj.property3 = 'property2' ;
myClassObj.property4 = 'property2' ;
myClassObj.property5 = 'property2 ';
myClassObj.say();
}
```

On triggering function I am getting the this error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Keep in mind both are in the same file.

Comment: No classes for javascript. Please read: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/3354-javascript-doesnt-need-class.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.say()` is the error. You are calling the function, not defining it.

```
 this.say = function () {
            alert('Say Hello');
        }
```

Comment: I think this is the public mothod of myClass and i can call it after initializing the object of myClass.

Comment: Moreover, it's better to define methods on the prototype if you want to use it as a prototype.

Comment: I'm surprised `this.say() = ...` isn't a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar And it is. But, the first terror is that an unknown method is called. If the say() method would exist, different error would be produced - `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: I just created a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/41724174?noredirect=1

Comment: THE problem is it gives the error on this line var myClassObj= new myClass();