# Why is funcname() = value; valid syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550413/how-to-initialize-a-class-object-in-javascript), someone had an incorrect class definition that included code like:

```
var myClass = function() {
    ...
    this.name() = function() { ... };
}
```

The obvious error is that the method should be defined with `this.name = ...`, without the parentheses after `name`. When you call the constructor, you get an error because `this.name` is not defined. I created a simpler example in the console:

```
foo() = 3;      // Causes: ReferenceError: foo is not defined
function foo() {};
foo() = 3;      // Causes: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Is there any context where a function could return something that can be assigned to? I don't think Javascript has references like C++ or PHP that can be assigned to. Why doesn't this cause a syntax error, rather than different errors depending on whether the function is defined or not?

Comment: The way the grammar is defined it's not a syntax error. I know of no way you could use the syntax to construct something semantically valid.

Comment: My confusion about this question is from the title: "Why is funcname() = value; valid syntax?" There is no situation where that is valid syntax. There will *always* be an error thrown.

Comment: Additionally, of course `ReferenceError` supersedes `SyntaxError` - in the example code the first thing the interpreter does is try to run an undefined function.

Comment: @ncksllvn But "an error" isn't the same as a syntax error. The spec seems pretty clear why it specifically is *not* a syntax error.

Comment: @ncksllvn The distinction between syntax and reference error is important. If the code appears in a function body (as in the question that originally prompted this), a syntax error will be reported when the containing function is defined. A reference error won't be reported until and unless the function is called.

Comment: Just to make sure I completely understand, something that throws an error 100% of the time still has valid syntax as long as that error isn't a syntax error? So `3 = 5` is valid syntax?

Comment: @ncksllvn It doesn't throw an error if you never execute it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quoting from the [ECMA Script 5.1 Specification for References](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7),

> For example, the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference. The behaviour of assignment could, instead, be explained entirely in terms of a case analysis on the syntactic form of the left-hand operand of an assignment operator, but for one difficulty: function calls are permitted to return references. This possibility is admitted purely for the sake of host objects. **No built-in ECMAScript function defined by this specification returns a reference and there is no provision for a user-defined function to return a reference. (Another reason not to use a syntactic case analysis is that it would be lengthy and awkward, affecting many parts of the specification.)**

---

> Is there any context where a function could return something that can be assigned to?

So, no. No user-defined function could return a reference to which we can assign a value.

> Why doesn't this cause a syntax error, rather than different errors depending on whether the function is defined or not?

As mentioned in the specification, the syntactic analysis would be *lengthy, awkward and affecting many parts of the specification*. So, the syntax check is not done.

Comment: So they did it to keep the spec simpler, and potentially allow for some vendor-specific features? I can accept that.